# Huge files in Visual Studio intermediate directory

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, qt, crash-dumps

Setting is a VS2010 solution with several (mainly c++) projects, solution is generated by cmake. Some of these projects are using Qt 5.2.1.

Recently I found some files in a corresponding intermediate directory which contain around 50 GBytes of data (sometimes even more). They have no type specified and of course I even can not see binaries of these files.

They are called e.g.

```
RDa09184     type:file   59.354.384 KB
```

Also there are rather small files which are named `RC....` instead of `RD....` e.g.

```
RCa03056     type:file            2 KB
```

My suspicion is they are kind of corrupt dump file (even though the project builds correctly).

Has anybody ever encountered similar problems? What kind of files are they? How can I setup which files to be generated in intermediate directory?

Comment: - They have no type specified and of course I even can not see binaries of these files.
Have you tried HEXEDITORs?

Comment: I use Vim and PsPad but I guess it won't be possible to read a file 8 times the size of RAM ?!

Comment: Thats wrong tools. Find any capable hexeditor. I use Hiew for example, there free demo available on offsite.
MOre can be found here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_hex_editors